# changing the parent li item class according to his content

Tags: css, angularjs

i have this simple unordered list

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Entertainment</p>
        <ul>
            <li><p>Lady GAGA</p></li>
            <li><p>Lady GAGA</p></li>
            <li><p>Lady GAGA</p></li>
            <li><p>Lady GAGA</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>Fasion</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>Animals</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and i want that the `<li>` that have `<ul>` inside of it will get a special class/style automatically, so if the content (the `ul`) will be move or removed the special class also removed from the parent `<li>`.

i'll be glad if it could be done in css or sass but in `ng-class` it's also fine.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you can't apply a rule to the parent of an element based on its children. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `ng-class` ? you're using AngularJS?

Comment: yes i'm using angularjs.i want to add a query to the <il> to check if there is content inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('li', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return $(element).find("ul").length;
            }, function(newValue) {
                if(newValue === 0) {
                    element.removeClass("hasSubList");
                }
                else {
                    element.addClass("hasSubList");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to check if content has changed you need to do it though javascript like this

```
$("#Id_of_the_ul").change(function(){
    // this is executed when any change occurs in the content of the <ul>
    //an if statement here for the change you want to detect

    $(this).parent().addClass("YourClass");
    // or
    $(this).parent().removeClass("YourClass");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to apply a property on `<ul>` element inside a `<li>`.  you can simply use css combinators for that like  :-

> li > ul {
>   // apply property
>   }

at this point if `ul` is not present in `li` then no property is applied on `ul`.

If you want to add and remove the style class according to the content then you need JavaScript for that.
@[Zoheiry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3481932/zoheiry) give good solution for that.

If you are using Angularjs then why are you not using JavaScript?